# React Native can't build app - IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I initialized a new project with react-native cli, opened it and tried to build it in IOS. it's the first time I ever tried doing it. first project ever.

and every time i try to build the project, it wouldn't install on the ios simulator, the build is failed and i get this error -

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Albums.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
Failed to chmod /Users/Eilon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E826A2C-E2AF-4C6C-84CE-6C52E6A0262D/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Bundle/Application/A2B54114-E373-4209-82F1-748BCC9899BB/Albums.app/Albums : No such file or directory
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.Albums
```

and it just stuck.

I tried reinstall Xcode few times and nothing helps.

any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Well After more than 2 days of struggling this. the problem was the folder structure. one of the folders had spaces in it's name, after removing the spaces everything worked fine.